# Fill "to", "cc" and "bcc" in group in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

I was wondering, is there a way to fill the fields "to", "cc" and "bcc" in group?
I mean, I usually send emails to one contact, and when I do (for this one in particular) I have to add the "cc" to the contacts partner and a "bcc" to a collegue o mine to keep him in the loop.

So, is there a way to automatise this process in Thunderbird (24.6.0 as of now)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the message as a template (New message -> Save as -> Template)

Now you can go to Templates folder and start from there each time (will not work if replying or forwarding).

Comment: Well, it might work for new messages, but I'll still have the problem when replying to an email. But If there's no other way, It might save some time, sometimes

Comment: I think it could be possible to make a Thunderbird extension to do it, if someone can/wants to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this by using the excellent [quicktext](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quicktext/) extension for Thunderbird.
With this, one could create a script named [AddRecipient](https://github.com/jobisoft/quicktext/wiki/Script:-AddRecipients) (from the community scripts)

```
let type = this.mVariables[0];
let adresses = this.mVariables[1].split(';');

var win = this.mWindow;

if(type == "to") {
  win.awAddRecipientsArray("addr_to", adresses);
}

if(type == "cc") {
  win.awAddRecipientsArray("addr_cc", adresses);
}

if(type == "bcc") {
  win.awAddRecipientsArray("addr_bcc", adresses);
}

if(type == "reply-to") {
  win.awAddRecipientsArray("addr_reply", adresses);
}
```

Then create a template and optionally add some text

```
[[SCRIPT=AddRecipients|to|John Doe <john.doe@example.com>]]
[[SCRIPT=AddRecipients|cc|Jane Doe <jane.doe@example.com>]]
Hello John, Jane

[[CURSOR]]

Kind regards
```

Et voilà ! You can start saving typing...